# Estou com dificuldades de terminar este programa, da erro na array e setlength

Tags: javascript, pascal, object-pascal

Escreva um programa em Pascal que lê um número não determinado de m valores, todos inteiros e positivos, um de cada vez. Se m for par, determine o produto destes.
Se m for ímpar e menor do que 12 calcule o factorial de m. Se m for ímpar e maior ou igua1 a 12 calcular e escrever a soma dos inteiros de l até m.
Exiba todos os resultados que o programa determinar com
mensagens apropriadas

```
program Trabalho_Exercicio_numero2;
uses
  Crt;
var
  dim, i,m, conta: Integer;
  produto, factorial, soma: real;
  x: array of Integer;
  resp: String;
BEGIN
  m:=1;
  while i < m+1 do
 begin
 ClrScr
   SetLength(x,m);
   m:=m+1;
   writeln ('Inserir valor? (S/N): ');
   Readln(resp);
   if ((resp = 'S') or (resp ='s')) then
   begin
   repeat
     begin
     write (i+1,'o valor inteiro e positivo: ');
     readln(x[i]);
     end;
     until(x[i]>0);
     i:=i+1;
   end
   else
   begin
     m:=i-1;
     conta:=m+1;
     WriteLn(conta,' valores lidos!');
   end;
 end;
End.
```

Comment: Bom dia! E qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Error 85: ";" expected.  Na fila da stelength (x,m);

Comment: Acredito que esteja faltando um `;` depois de `ClrScr`.